# Ignore Whitespace when working with SelectSingleNode and Xpath

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

Let's assume we have the following `xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bookstore>
  <book genre="novel" publicationdate="1997" ISBN="1-861001-57-8">
    <title>Pride And Prejudice</title>
    <author>
      <first-name>Jane</first-name>
      <last-name>Austen</last-name>
    </author>
    <price>24.95</price>
  </book>
  <book genre="textbook" publicationdate="2013" ISBN="1-861002-30-1">
    <title>Head First C#</title>
    <author>
      <first-name>Jennifer</first-name>
      <last-name>Greene</last-name>
    </author>
    <price>29.95</price>
  </book>
</bookstore>
```

I want to check if the element `book` with the attribute `genre="novel"` exist and if not add it.

I've written the following code and it works beautifully. However, if someone edits the xml file and accidentally places an extra space between the word "novel" and the double quotes, `genre=" novel "`, or let's say I'm an idiot and added the extra space when creating the attribute's value the xpath won't be valid any more and the code will add a node when one already exists. Is there a way to use `SelectSingleNode` in a way that it will ignore whitespace?

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"C:\Users\anonymous\Documents\file.xml");

string xpath = @"/bookstore/book [@genre='novel']";
var rootNode = doc.SelectSingleNode(@"/bookstore");
var bookNode = doc.SelectSingleNode(xpath);

if (bookNode == null)
{
  XmlNode newNode = doc.CreateElement("book");
  XmlAttribute genreAttribute = doc.CreateAttribute("genre");
  genreAttribute.Value = @"novel";
  newNode.Attributes.Append(genreAttribute);
  rootNode.AppendChild(newNode);
}
doc.Save(@"C:\Users\anonymous\Documents\file.xml");
```

Comment: Do you particularly need to use XmlDocument and XPath? I suspect this is feasible using something like a trim function, but I'd personally recommend using LINQ to XML instead.

Comment: It's not in the specs or anything but it's my first attempt working with xpath and basically that's the way I managed to make it work. I'm certain there are a million better ways to do this. I'd appreciate a link to an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `normalize-space()` XPath function:

```
string xpath = @"/bookstore/book [normalize-space(@genre)='novel']";
```

This will trim any leading or trailing whitespace characters, but it will also normalize any sequence of whitespace characters in between to just one single whitespace.

Note: To be more precise, this still does not completely "ignore whitespace". Singleton whitespaces as in

```
<book genre="no vel"/>
```

will be kept and are relevant. If you'd like to completely ignore whitespace, you could use the `translate()` function:

```
string xpath = @"/bookstore/book [translate(@genre,' ','')='novel']";
```

Comment: No, I wanted to ignore the extra whitespace, not eliminate it completely. But thanks for the tip.